# Is it possible to use one bib file for the whole thesis and have generate Chapter by Chapter References list?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I browsed around and didn't quite find what I am looking for.

What I am looking for is a way to:
- use ONE BIB file for the whole thesis. 
- have latex generate a chapter by chapter reference list.

Is that possible? How?

Any help is appreciated.

P.S: It looks like everyone is making a different bib file for each chapter.  :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None off the existing solutions (from chapterbib to biblatex/biber) cares about how you organize the bib-entries in the bib-files. You can use one or ten bib-files. With biblatex you can use refsections or refsegments to split the bibliographies. Here an example for refsegment. I used `\section` instead of `\chapter` to get everything on one page, but it works for `\chapter` too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[refsegment=section,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{first}
\cite{doody}

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,title=first bib]

\section{second}
\cite{herrmann, doody}

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,title=second bib]
\end{document}
```

[image]