# Having one bib file but generate references per each chapter

Tags: bibliographies

I know that `cite` and `biblatex` are incompatible. Also,  `natbib` and `bibtex.` I have looked at many Q & A regarding having bib per chapters, but those except  [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294229/is-it-possible-to-use-one-bib-file-for-the-whole-thesis-and-have-generate-chapte) were dealing with multiple bibs. I have just one big bib and 5 chapters (separated .tex files).

I would like to generate chapters-wised references instead of one at the end. Here is my structure and I am using `Pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex*2 + viewpdf` :

Currently, it generated one reference at the end, but If I want to have that chapter-wised and I put my bib lines at the end of each chapters' tex file, it gives me error. This task should be straightforward, but it is not.

```
\usepackage[cite]
\usepackage ...         
\makeindex

\include{foreword}
\include{preface}

\tableofcontents


\mainmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{part}
\selectlanguage{english}

\include{1-survey/survey}
\input{2-}
\input{3-}
\input{4-}
\input{5-}
\selectlanguage{english}

\backmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\printindex
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib/survey}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Now, as suggested by [biblatex reference](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), `biblatex` is able to provide multiple references with this structure:

```
\documentclass{...}
\usepackage[...]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{...}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I have commented my `include{cite}` and added those instead of `\bibliography` and I am recieving this error:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015) The top-level auxiliary file: 
book.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: foreword.aux A level-1 auxiliary file:
preface.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: acronym.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: 
part.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: 1-survey/definitions.aux A level-1 
auxiliary file: 4-/definitions.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: 
5-/definitions.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file book.aux 
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file book.aux I found no \bibstyle 
command---while reading file book.aux (There were 3 error messages)
```

Is there a way I don't change my compilation flow with this? Apparently `pdflatex` and `latex` are having differences on usage.

Comment: See *§ 3.7.4 Bibliography sections*, pp. 82-83 in the `biblatex` documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard for the reference. I did as suggested, please see my updated question.

Comment: Do you have any reason to not use  `biblatex`?

Comment: please see my updated question. In the doc it says I have to use `latex` and then `biber`. Latex doesn't compiler and I don't have biber. Is there a chance I keep my old compilation flow (pdflatex,...) ?

Comment: Which distribution do you have?

Comment: I have `texlive/2014/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex` and using them in `texmaker`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60711/discussion-between-bernard-and-amir).

Comment: I think you want something like the `chapterbib` or `multibib` packages. No need to use BibLaTeX.

Comment: @TH, Does `multibib` supports one bib and many references ?

Comment: Looks like `bibunits` was the package I was thinking of. I'm afraid you'll have to read the documentation for the packages or wait for another suggestion. I don't have sufficient time right now. Sorry.