# One .bib file with separated chapter files

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

Edit: Solved - soltion by @moewe - Run Biber instead of BibTeX

MacOS,TeXstudio 2.12.18

This has been asked but I can't seem to find a solution that works for me, some suggest the same thing however copying the answer doesn't yeild the same output (e.g. [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294229/is-it-possible-to-use-one-bib-file-for-the-whole-thesis-and-have-generate-chapte))

I'm writing a thesis which has individual chapters in their own .tex files.

I would like to have a bibliography at the end of each chapter, where the .bib file is the same file used in each instance.

I have tried running the code listed in the example thread above and I can't even get it to work, let alone when I am looking at using separate .tex files.

Code from the example, amended for my own .bib file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[refsegment=section,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lib.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{first}
\cite{bibid}

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,title=first bib]

\section{second}
\cite{Albonetti2005,An2012}

\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,title=second bib]
\end{document}
```

With the above code it yields no bibliographies in the output at all. The log states:

```
Process started: bibtex "test2".aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019)
The top-level auxiliary file: test2.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test2.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test2.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test2.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)



Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test2".tex

Process exited normally
```

So, I must be missing something, but I am unsure what at this point. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that your editor runs BibTeX on your document, but you need to run Biber instead of BibTeX. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help with configuring your editor to run Biber. (I just confirmed that the code as shown produces the expected result when compiled with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX. - Note that I used a different `.bib` file because I don't have your `lib.bib`, but that shouldn't be an issue.)

Comment: @moewe Thanks! That has now got the citations working and bibliographies showing!